# What is the difference between OWASP Java Encoder and OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer?

Tags: java, xss, owasp

I need to handle user input in my Java application to protect against Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

I found [OWASP Java Encoder](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-encoder/) and [OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-html-sanitizer/) on the OWASP website.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: Sanitizing allows some HTML (e.g. `<b>`), encoding "replaces" all HTML. Sanitizing is more difficult and error-prone than encoding.